# How can you crop an image to pieces in javafx in order to create a game puzzle with tiles?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to do a project with javafx but I can't create the figures to a puzzle game with tiles, in order to push them with the click of a button. How can an Image be cropped and saved as an individual tile ?

Answer (score 2):

The [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) class is used to display an image. It has a [`viewport` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty) that represents the portion of the image it is viewing. So you can create multiple image views from the same image, each with a different viewport: then you can add the image views to a pane of some kind, register mouse handlers on them, etc.

If you actually need to store each piece as an individual image, you can [`snapshot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) the image view to create a new `Image` from it. You'll probably find you don't need this, however.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try PixelReader and WritableImage APIs from JavaFX platform.

Comment: IMHO this answer shouldn't be deleted. It may be very vague, but points out a way to do this (although James D's approach seems superior to me). @nawazish-stackoverflow: Maybe you could improve the quality of the answer by adding a few more details and maybe some code.

Comment: @fabian sure I will try to do that.